# Initializing a large jagged array takes over 1 GB of RAM and crashes with StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, arrays

When I compile this piece of C# code [(full text)](https://www.nayuki.io/priv/ArrayTest.cs) and run the [ArrayTest.exe](https://www.nayuki.io/priv/ArrayTest.exe), the process hangs for a few seconds, consumes 1 GB of RAM, and crashes with StackOverflowException. Why?

```
public struct Point { }

public class ArrayTest {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        Point[][] array = {
            new Point[]{new Point(), new Point(), /* ... 296 omitted ... */, new Point(), new Point()},
            new Point[]{new Point(), new Point(), /* ... 296 omitted ... */, new Point(), new Point()},
            /* ... 296 omitted ... */
            new Point[]{new Point(), new Point(), /* ... 296 omitted ... */, new Point(), new Point()},
            new Point[]{new Point(), new Point(), /* ... 296 omitted ... */, new Point(), new Point()},
        };
        /* Do nothing and return */
    }
}
```

I am using Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.0.30319.33440 for Microsoft (R) .NET Framework 4.5. I'm just calling csc.exe on the command line and executing the compiled EXE. The problem disappears when I add the csc `/optimize` flag. The snippet above is indeed the entire code I am testing with - there is no useful work being performed in Main() after the array is initialized.

---

Problem context: I was trying to hard-code a set of numerical test cases into a program. In Java, JavaScript, or Python, the code would innocently look like this and work properly:

```
class Point { int x; int y; }

Point[][] data = {  // About 1000 entries
    {new Point(1, 2)},
    {new Point(5, 3), new Point(0, 6), new Point(1, 8)},  // Different length
    ... et cetera ...
};
for (Point[] thing : data):
    test(thing);
```

But when I tried to compiled code like this in C#, the array initialization took a noticeable amount of time (~5 seconds), even before the for-loop with the `test()` could start to execute.

My actual code has been reduced to the MVCE above, where `struct Point` contains no fields, and `Main()` contains just the array initialization and no useful work.

Comment: why the downvotes?

Comment: I think the title I gave is not descriptive and potentially inflammatory

Comment: @Everyone: Please edit the title and tags as you see fit. I honestly don't know how to classify my problem

Comment: I don't know what you're doing, but I just created a 4x300 "jagged" array of structs with x/y properties with no problems. Granted, I didn't do it in initializers (if you think I'm adding all those even with copy and paste, you're crazy), but still, it shouldn't be that different.

Comment: @itsme86 I didn't see a problem in small data sets either. I believe that making the test case 300×300 is necessary to trigger the behavior

Comment: @Nayuki Even at 300x300, it's no problem. ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe is below 6MB after allocation. I'm just instantiating the points in a nested loop.

Comment: You *hard-coded* this?  Hard to believe.  Crystal ball says that it is actually the C# compiler that keels over on this, not the CLR.  That happens, the parser was written to parse human code, not machine-generated code.  Use a file instead.

Comment: @HansPassant I hard-coded the data values for a temporary test to be discarded. The C# compiler runs just fine and outputs the EXE. Running ArrayTest.exe produces the bad behavior.

Comment: Use a file instead.

Comment: I can switch to using an input file instead. However I still want to understand, am I triggering some kind of O(n^2) or other undesirable behavior due to my misunderstanding of the language or runtime?

Comment: I just manually added 300x300 in the initializer in linqpad, and the only thing was linqpad's intellisense made it take forever to load after a 70x300, but compile and run went perfectly fine.

Comment: If you're going to claim a performance problem, it behooves you to provide a good [mcve], along with clear explanation of what performance you are observing, what performance you expect instead, and a rational reason for why you think you should be able to expect that performance.

Comment: @PeterDuniho This is already my best attempt at an MCVE. I removed the struct fields and the code in Main(). It is 100% reproducible on my system. I documented the unreasonable memory usage and crash on initialization. What objections do you have?

Comment: @Nayuki Can you please include a complete function without the comments?  Something i can copy/paste and run.

Comment: @MattClark Link added, thanks for your patience

Comment: Upvoted... i see no reason why anyone should downvote this. While it is rather insane to hard-code that many values, it's still a viable performance question.

Comment: _"This is already my best attempt at an MCVE"_ -- then you have no idea what a [mcve] actually is. Please read that link again. Please also read [ask], and especially the pages linked at the bottom of that page.

Comment: I didn't try to reproduce and investigate your C#, because I agree with others that as it stands, you haven't provided a usable MCVE. But from the Python code I provided, the only hint I can get is this: your "array" (C#) variable is indeed a jagged array -- that is, a reference type ultimately; however, in the for-loop you're doing 2 things that are not innocent and for which code is (still) missing towards a MCVE in C# (1) you're invoking a "test" function, so nobody knows if that one is recursive, somehow (2) you're iterating over elements of the jagged array, which are arrays of structs...

Comment: ... meaning you're likely copying 1 or more kilobytes for each stack frame of test, and possibly boxed later on in "test" 's body. Grossly guess-timating, that means that *only* a couple dozen thousands of calls into that "test" function would be enough to put hundreds of Mb of memory pressure (up to 1Gb?) on the GC and/or the thread call stack. 'Hope this helps.

Comment: @YSharp I had not made myself clear in the post - the bad C# program simply declares and initializes the array. There is literally nothing in Main() after the array is constructed.

Comment: @Nayuki i took your code and ran it with some timers around it, it only took 4 ms to run. Am I missing something?

Comment: @PeterDuniho They've literally included a link that allows people to copy & paste the code. Not sure what else you're expecting.

Comment: @MattClark I tried putting DateTime.Now around the array declaration, but it took 1 ms to run. Maybe the execution time is spent on CLR initialization?

Comment: @Rob: I'm expecting a) for the question to be entirely self-contained -- it is a strict community standard that all Stack Overflow questions not have to rely on links to external resources, and b) that even if not self-contained, the provided code actually **reproduce the claimed problem**.

Comment: Where did you get your compiler, which you say is version `4.0.30319.33440`? I have VS2013 and VS2015 installed, and csc.exe reports versions `12.0.40629.0` and `1.3.1.60616`, respectively. Your code runs fine on my machine, using either compiler. I haven't seen a single person state that they've been able to reproduce your claimed problem, and several (including myself) who cannot. You need to do more legwork yourself to figure out what it is about your configuration that causes you to observe this issue.

Comment: @PeterDuniho This is an exception to the rule where including the entire code verbatim achieves nothing, and just makes the question unreadable. It's perfectly fine to include an external link to the code. If you feel differently, you have the ability to edit it. Secondly, the code *is* repeatable - OP claims it happens every time for them. The fact that it may not be reproducible on *every* system does not matter. Producing code that failed the same way on every system would require understanding *why* it fails in the first place (and thus answering the question).

Comment: @Rob: _"It's perfectly fine to include an external link to the code"_ -- baloney. There is no "exception to the rule", because a question on Stack Overflow is useful only if it can _remain_ useful indefinitely. As long as the question requires access to external resources, that cannot be assured. In any case, so far not a single person has stated that they've reproduced the problem...are you claiming that you have?

Comment: @Rob: _"Producing code that failed the same way on every system would require understanding why it fails in the first place"_ -- I disagree. But let's suppose for a moment that's true. Then that makes this a completely useless question. Not all questions that a person can ask actually belong on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @PeterDuniho The question *is* on stackoverflow, and will remain useful indefinitely. It's simply not copy & pasteable, it requires slight effort for future readers. That trumps having a question completely unreadable, IMO. As I said, *you are able to edit it* if you wish. OP says they can reproduce the result. Assuming they are showing the exact code, that is acceptable. Just because a bug is obscure and hard to reproduce across all systems, doesn't invalid the question. Personally, LINQPad successfully compiles and runs the code, but crashes after about 5 seconds.

Comment: FYI: I found the compiler that is delivered with .NET, in a directly named `v4.0.30319`. But that compiler reports its version as `4.6.1038.0` (I have .NET 4.6 installed on Windows 10). At best, you are looking at a compiler bug that is irrelevant to anyone using up-to-date tools, and at worst, even an older compiler handles this just fine and you have something else in your configuration you're not telling us but which is relevant.

Comment: @Rob: _"Just because a bug is obscure and hard to reproduce across all systems, doesn't invalid the question"_ -- you are entitled to your opinion, but as far as I'm concerned, you're completely off-base here. This isn't just "obscure". It's not reproducible by anyone other than the person who posted the question. That's exactly the _opposite_ of the situation that providing a good [mcve] is supposed to ensure. And if the external links rot away, no one will even be able to satisfy themselves that the problem is non-existent, never mind make use of the question.

Comment: Alright. So, I took the code you linked as is, then added a Console.WriteLine(...) / Console.ReadKey() at the end of Main, and ran it from a full fledged VS 2015. Besides the VS' parser / intelli sense / code formatter choking a bit on trying to match all the "{" and "}" at authoring time, prior to the build (because of your huge jagged array init) it then ran just fine in a few milliseconds, ending up with only a 2Mb or so footprint of itself on the CLR heap. I have no idea what is your C# dev environment, but I would fix it first before writing other C# programs. 'HTH,

Answer (score 7):

Okay, I started compiling debug/release versions of your class file. With the VS 2015 compiler found in the 14.0 version of tools, the output for the IL is identical. This covers the reason people weren't noticing issues.

Debug vs release in the previous compiler used in VS 2013 is pretty immediately damning. Output the the executable in debug mode is 2,091 kb. IL from the release version indicates it just ignores the actual object since it's never utilized. Okay, fine. I'll compare VS 2015 Debug IL to the VS 2013 Debug IL.

I've changed the array size to 3x3 for brevity.

Here is the output from the 2015 IL:

```
  .method public hidebysig static void  Main() cil managed
  {
    .entrypoint
    // Code size       45 (0x2d)
    .maxstack  4
    .locals init (valuetype Point[][] V_0)
    IL_0000:  nop
    IL_0001:  ldc.i4.4
    IL_0002:  newarr     valuetype Point[]
    IL_0007:  dup
    IL_0008:  ldc.i4.0
    IL_0009:  ldc.i4.3
    IL_000a:  newarr     Point
    IL_000f:  stelem.ref
    IL_0010:  dup
    IL_0011:  ldc.i4.1
    IL_0012:  ldc.i4.3
    IL_0013:  newarr     Point
    IL_0018:  stelem.ref
    IL_0019:  dup
    IL_001a:  ldc.i4.2
    IL_001b:  ldc.i4.3
    IL_001c:  newarr     Point
    IL_0021:  stelem.ref
    IL_0022:  dup
    IL_0023:  ldc.i4.3
    IL_0024:  ldc.i4.3
    IL_0025:  newarr     Point
    IL_002a:  stelem.ref
    IL_002b:  stloc.0
    IL_002c:  ret
  } // end of method ArrayTest::Main
```

The main difference between this and the release mode code is the additional nop instruction.

Here is the output for the 2012/2013 version of the compiler:

```
  .method public hidebysig static void  Main() cil managed
  {
    .entrypoint
    // Code size       307 (0x133)
    .maxstack  4
    .locals init (valuetype Point[][] V_0,
             valuetype Point[][] V_1,
             valuetype Point[] V_2,
             valuetype Point V_3)
    IL_0000:  nop
    IL_0001:  ldc.i4.4
    IL_0002:  newarr     valuetype Point[]
    IL_0007:  stloc.1
    IL_0008:  ldloc.1
    IL_0009:  ldc.i4.0
    IL_000a:  ldc.i4.3
    IL_000b:  newarr     Point
    IL_0010:  stloc.2
    IL_0011:  ldloc.2
    IL_0012:  ldc.i4.0
    IL_0013:  ldelema    Point
    IL_0018:  ldloca.s   V_3
    IL_001a:  initobj    Point
    IL_0020:  ldloc.3
    IL_0021:  stobj      Point
    IL_0026:  ldloc.2
    IL_0027:  ldc.i4.1
    IL_0028:  ldelema    Point
    IL_002d:  ldloca.s   V_3
    IL_002f:  initobj    Point
    IL_0035:  ldloc.3
    IL_0036:  stobj      Point
    IL_003b:  ldloc.2
    IL_003c:  ldc.i4.2
    IL_003d:  ldelema    Point
    IL_0042:  ldloca.s   V_3
    IL_0044:  initobj    Point
    IL_004a:  ldloc.3
    IL_004b:  stobj      Point
    IL_0050:  ldloc.2
    IL_0051:  stelem.ref
    IL_0052:  ldloc.1
    IL_0053:  ldc.i4.1
    IL_0054:  ldc.i4.3
    IL_0055:  newarr     Point
    IL_005a:  stloc.2
    IL_005b:  ldloc.2
    IL_005c:  ldc.i4.0
    IL_005d:  ldelema    Point
    IL_0062:  ldloca.s   V_3
    IL_0064:  initobj    Point
    IL_006a:  ldloc.3
    IL_006b:  stobj      Point
    IL_0070:  ldloc.2
    IL_0071:  ldc.i4.1
    IL_0072:  ldelema    Point
    IL_0077:  ldloca.s   V_3
    IL_0079:  initobj    Point
    IL_007f:  ldloc.3
    IL_0080:  stobj      Point
    IL_0085:  ldloc.2
    IL_0086:  ldc.i4.2
    IL_0087:  ldelema    Point
    IL_008c:  ldloca.s   V_3
    IL_008e:  initobj    Point
    IL_0094:  ldloc.3
    IL_0095:  stobj      Point
    IL_009a:  ldloc.2
    IL_009b:  stelem.ref
    IL_009c:  ldloc.1
    IL_009d:  ldc.i4.2
    IL_009e:  ldc.i4.3
    IL_009f:  newarr     Point
    IL_00a4:  stloc.2
    IL_00a5:  ldloc.2
    IL_00a6:  ldc.i4.0
    IL_00a7:  ldelema    Point
    IL_00ac:  ldloca.s   V_3
    IL_00ae:  initobj    Point
    IL_00b4:  ldloc.3
    IL_00b5:  stobj      Point
    IL_00ba:  ldloc.2
    IL_00bb:  ldc.i4.1
    IL_00bc:  ldelema    Point
    IL_00c1:  ldloca.s   V_3
    IL_00c3:  initobj    Point
    IL_00c9:  ldloc.3
    IL_00ca:  stobj      Point
    IL_00cf:  ldloc.2
    IL_00d0:  ldc.i4.2
    IL_00d1:  ldelema    Point
    IL_00d6:  ldloca.s   V_3
    IL_00d8:  initobj    Point
    IL_00de:  ldloc.3
    IL_00df:  stobj      Point
    IL_00e4:  ldloc.2
    IL_00e5:  stelem.ref
    IL_00e6:  ldloc.1
    IL_00e7:  ldc.i4.3
    IL_00e8:  ldc.i4.3
    IL_00e9:  newarr     Point
    IL_00ee:  stloc.2
    IL_00ef:  ldloc.2
    IL_00f0:  ldc.i4.0
    IL_00f1:  ldelema    Point
    IL_00f6:  ldloca.s   V_3
    IL_00f8:  initobj    Point
    IL_00fe:  ldloc.3
    IL_00ff:  stobj      Point
    IL_0104:  ldloc.2
    IL_0105:  ldc.i4.1
    IL_0106:  ldelema    Point
    IL_010b:  ldloca.s   V_3
    IL_010d:  initobj    Point
    IL_0113:  ldloc.3
    IL_0114:  stobj      Point
    IL_0119:  ldloc.2
    IL_011a:  ldc.i4.2
    IL_011b:  ldelema    Point
    IL_0120:  ldloca.s   V_3
    IL_0122:  initobj    Point
    IL_0128:  ldloc.3
    IL_0129:  stobj      Point
    IL_012e:  ldloc.2
    IL_012f:  stelem.ref
    IL_0130:  ldloc.1
    IL_0131:  stloc.0
    IL_0132:  ret
  } // end of method ArrayTest::Main
```

So, in the 2012/2013 compiler you're using, debug mode is doing a very large number of stack allocations, likely so that you can intellisense the entire jagged array structure during edit and continue, or possibly so that you might step into each individual object construction. I'm not sure about this at all.

I am no expert on IL, but it appears to me that it's allocating for each Point, then again for each Array, then again for the jagged array, leading to way too many allocations.

Comment: Where do you see the stack allocations? Note that the "evaluation stack" isn't a real physical stack.

Comment: Hey fair enough, as I said this is a bit outside of my area of expertise. I think that where the .locals are ultimately stored for value types is on the stack. If you know differently I would love to hear about it.

Comment: That is true, but there are only four locals, and they all are arrays, which are reference types, except for the last one which is a single Point instance. The actual array contents are allocated with `newarr`, which allocates outside the evaluation stack, and *I suppose* in practice allocates in a GC heap.

Comment: I think that V_3 is a regular value type. The `stobj Point` instruction seems to suggest the value type is being pushed from the evaluation stack to an address in memory. Whether this is on the stack or the heap is going to be up to the CLR, if I'm not mistaken. Thanks for pointing out the difference between the evaluation stack and the physical stack, I needed the vocabulary. I'm thinking the overflow may be that debug mode lets you step into each individual instantiation and frames are trying to stay around until the initialization is complete, but this is just conjecture.